Jenkins running on AWS EC2 instance can't connect to updates.jenkins.io, to download the plugins
I have an ec2 instance in free trial and managed to successfully install and run Jenkins on it. Now I am accessing it's UI at port 8080 through my local host. But when I go to the manage Jenkins> Plugins tab, it shows an error:

There were errors checking the update sites: SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out

When I go to the advanced tab it shows error:

Unable to connect to the URL: https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json


java.net.ConnectException: HTTP connect timed out
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.MultiExchange.toTimeoutException(MultiExchange.java:581)
Caused: java.net.http.HttpConnectTimeoutException: HTTP connect timed out
...

I am managing the internet connections through an ipv6 address, and connecting through aws ec2-instance-connect.
I verified that my internet connection is working as I could download the jenkins and other programs from yum repository.
Is the error caused by me using ipv6 address and no public ipv4 address? Perhaps the updates.jenkins.io can't be accessed by an ipv6 client?
Please help me explain the cause of this problem and how to fix it.
I tried doing
curl -i https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json
but it timed out too. So, I thought if it was a network issue (ipv4 vs ipv6)..
I have searched for similar problems on google, tried downloading the plugin(github plugin) on my local host and uploading it to the aws ec2 instance so that i can use the jenkins app offline and so on..
Edit 1:
I found a different mirror site that responded on doing curl -i <mirror_url> and decided to install plugins manually.
Mirrors List: https://get.jenkins.io/index.html?mirrorstats
I chose https://repo.jing.rocks/jenkins/plugins/ as it responded successfully when i tried curl. I also tried changing the url on the plugins>advanced tab but it showed the same error.
Downloading all  the dependencies, and maintaining the versions was troublesome as sometimes the /latest didn't contain the actual latest version..
